# Error: undefined method `like' for Sequel:Module

Tags: ruby, sequel

I get this error:

```
Error: undefined method `like' for Sequel:Module
```

using:

```
@info = DB[:info].where(Sequel.like(:content, "%#{params[:sc]}%")) if params[:sc]
```

I found the example code in Sequel's documentation:

```
DB[:artists].where(Sequel.like(:name, 'A%'))
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Sequel are you running?  The documentation assumes the latest version, so if you aren't using the latest version, you should upgrade.